# How should I deal with event handlers of objects that I want to delete?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was wondering what is the proper and least verbose way to deal with objects that have event handlers registered.

Lets take this example:

```
const mqtt = require('mqtt')
var users = []

function createClient(){
var user = { 'name': 'barney', 'age': 36, 'client': client: mqtt.connect('mqtt://127.0.0.1'), 'active': false }
user.client.on("message",messageHandler.bind(user))
users.push(user)
}

function messageHandler(topic, message){
console.log(`'User' ${this.name} received ${message} on ${topic}`)
}

createClient()
delete users[0].client
users = []
```

Now the client object is gone but the event handler seems to be still alive as I now get an error thrown because user is undefined.

I would have assumed that the garbage collector would take care of event handlers of objects that don't exist anymore.

Edit: It seems I simplified too much. I changed the code to reflect an actual existing object. mqtt comes from [mqtt.js](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js/)

It seems it is important what the object does/is. I would appreciate an answer that explains why that is as it seems to be very related as to why I am having my issue. I don't need help with fixing my code, I want to better understand how objects and event handlers work and how the garbage collection deals with the. From the resources I read so far the behaviour I'm getting seems confusing to me.

Comment: Can you add the code of `Dog` object?

Comment: so unbind the event. Hard to tell anything since we have no clue what you Dog object is.

Comment: Well if the event still fires then the object must still exist. Where do those "bark" events come from? The `delete` operation deletes a property; it doesn't affect the property's value. If another reference to that Dog instance persists, the object won't be garbage collected.

Comment: Provide a **runnable** [mcve] that reproduces the issue

Comment: I just made it up to serve as an equivalent example. My actual code is very large, I wanted to avoid confusion by posting a lot of irrelevant code.
Is it important what the Dog object does? I get this behaviour with every object/class that I use in this way.

Comment: @PTS what matters is if something somewhere maintains a reference to the instantiated Dog instance. Like, if `new Dog("beagle")` adds the dog to a `dogs` array. Then deleting the "dog" property from the user won't get rid of that dog object.

Comment: The point is, it depends on how the event dispatcher is implemented, we don't see the code, and it also depends whether other objects have a reference to dog as well. `delete` doesn't garbage collect anything, it just removes a property from an object. Instead of using delete you should use `unbind` if the method exists on dog, but again, we do not know how your event dispatcher is coded.

Comment: Also in the posted example you wouldn't get an error due to the user being undefined, because nothing in the code you posted can change the fact that the dog "bark" handler contains a reference to the user object; it's bound to it.

Comment: Sorry for simplifying too much, I added an example I acutally use in my code. Every event handler I use for my mqtt client connection is dangling after I deleted the object that hold the client object.

Comment: OK, well you bind the mqtt instance to `user` but then you reference `this.user` in the handler code. Is there a "user" property on the user instance?

Comment: Imagine `on` says something like this: `handlers[object][eventtype].push(handler)`. Assuming `handlers` is a normal object and not a WeakMap, it will hold reference to your object and prevent GC. If it is a WeakMap, it (and all the handlers) would disappear the moment all references go away (not including that one). So just on this one case, you can see how we can't know exactly what is happening with your object, since we simply don't have the in-depth access to code (or probably even the inclination to do so) that this kind of analysis would require.

Comment: Thanks for that input. This in-depth knowledge is what I'm looking for. I didn't know there was such a thing as WeakMaps in JS.
How can I know what I am dealing with?

Comment: @Pointy There is, its the name "Barney". I guess a wrote a bit of a poor example for my problem but code wise its the same as I use it in my larger application.

Answer (score 4):

If you are brought to do this often, you can create your own function to handle this case. For example :

```
const unbindAndDelete = (element, event = 'bark', handler = 'barkHandler') => {
  element.removeEventListener(event, handler);
  delete element;
}
```

But be sure to pass to it a valid `element` to delete, i.e. an object property. Javascript will not let you do this on variable.

Comment: Ok so I have to remove the event handler manually everytime even though the object itself shouldn't exist anymore when I called delte?
Of course given that the array was holding the only reference.

Comment: Yes, i suppose that an event force to persist the in-memory location of the object, because of how javascript engine work, and specifically how the garbage collector work. It's quite complicated, and I don't know that much of this subject, but you will find some really interesting answer if you take a look at how javascript engines work.

In short, if a pointer (your event) point to a memory adress (your object property), it will tell the garbage to not collect it. And understand by this that invoke `delete` do not really delete things ...

Comment: Thanks, I guess that makes sense. Otherwise anonymous functions for callbacks wouldnt work either.